# material design to a stock AOSP ROM app (like Settings, Email etc)

Tags: material-design, android-source, android-appcompat

Is it possible to use the AppCompat library for material design in a complete pre-Lollipop ROM. When I mean ROM, example Email, Settings, Browser everything. I can see for a single app I could use app compat

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'

But how could I do it for app inside a ROM? I am very confident that this must be possible, as if I install PlayServices in a Kitkat-AOSP ROM (from Galaxy S), I can get material design email (Gmail) which is propreitary.

I am wondering if one needs to make changes to Android.mk or AndroidManifest.xml to some how include "appcompat"?

many thanks

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Apps have to be specifically written to use Material Design. The AppCompat support library helps you add MD to pre-Lollipop devices.

Apps like Gmail were updated to include Material Design. There is no way to simply update an existing APK to include MD.